# Cannot add more arguments to procedure in pgAdmin 4, Ubuntu 22.10. How can I fix the add option or add arguments programatically?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, pgadmin-4

I am using pgAdmin 4 to create and update stored procedures. I want to add more arguments to one existing procedure but the add option is not available:
[image: Without add option when modifying procedure]

What I expect to see is the "+" option, as it appears when I create a procedure [image: With add option when creating procedure]

The only answer I know is to re-create the procedure, but I think there must be a better answer.

How can I make the "+" option appear?
If it is not possible, how can I add arguments to the procedure using queries?

More details: using the version 6.17 of pgAdmin 4.

Any advice is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The only option is to drop the function and create a new one, which is not an expensive operation. `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` is only possible if the signature doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

The "Properties" option seems not to be a comfortable way to work, found this fast way to add arguments using pgAdmin4:

- On the menu, right-click on procedure.
- Instead of using "properties" option, use Scripts > Create script.
- On resulting script, uncomment "drop" line, then add arguments. Also do all changes required and run script.